# How to know if removed File monitored by File Observer is a Directory or a File

Tags: android, file, fileobserver

I'm using FileObserver to monitor changes in folders.

Events are triggered as expected but I have problem making a distinction between Files and Directories in the events `DELETE` and `MOVED_FROM`, since after the event is triggered, calling both `File.isFile()` and `File.isDirectory()` is false (which make sense).

Is there an efficient way to make this check before file is removed? I do have a workaround by listing all files in effected folder, however it's inefficient.

Fileobserver code:

```
 mFileObserver = new FileObserver(DIRECTORY.getPath()) {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(int event, String path) {
                event &= FileObserver.ALL_EVENTS;
                switch (event) {
                    case (CREATE):
                    case (MOVED_TO):
                        Log.d(TAG, "Added to folder: " + DIRECTORY + " --> File name " + path);
                        addChild(path);
                        break;
                    case (DELETE):
                    case (MOVED_FROM):
                        Log.d(TAG, "Removed from folder " + DIRECTORY + " --> File name " + path);                            
                        removeChild(path);
                        break;
                    case (MOVE_SELF):
                    case (DELETE_SELF):
                        removeDirectory();
                        break;
                }
            }               
        };
```

EDIT:

This is how is File/Folder is evaluated in `removeChild(String)`

```
private void removeChild(String name) {

        mFileObserver.stopWatching();

        String filepath = this.getAbsolutePath() + separator + name;
        File file = new File(filepath);
        if (file.exists())
            Log.d(TAG, "Exists");
        else Log.d(TAG, " Does not Exists");

        if (file.isDirectory())
            Log.d(TAG, "is Directory");
        else Log.d(TAG, " is  NOT Directory");

        if (file.isFile())
            Log.d(TAG, "is File");
        else Log.d(TAG, " is  NOT File");
    }
```

And the relevant logcat output is:

```
04-03 12:37:20.714 5819-6352:  Removed from folder /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/GR --> File name ic_alarm_white_24dp.png
04-03 12:37:20.714 5819-6352:  Does not Exists
04-03 12:37:20.714 5819-6352:  is  NOT Directory
04-03 12:37:20.714 5819-6352:  is  NOT File
```

Comment: probably you can create a `File` object from the `path`, and check it's  `isDirectory()`

Comment: This is first thing I tried, doesn't work. Creating an instance of `File` is still non-existent File. Creating actual File/Folder on device would be inefficient even if it was possible, since I do not know which type of  "file" to create.

Comment: can you show example of that you get in `path`?

Comment: "Path" is actually a name, as you can see in updated question.

Comment: As I can see you have a directory as well as a pth inside of it. Probably you were checking incorrectly for `isDirectory()`?

Comment: It's not impossible, but extremely unlikely, since adding file is done using the same `parent` + `name` combination, and it works flawlessly. Observer is observing folders, as stated in question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there an efficient way to make this check before file is removed?

Unfortunately, not that I'm aware of.  Which makes sense - filesystem **events** are things that have already happened.

[`FileObserver` uses `inotify`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html) to get events.  A good description of `inotify` functionality can be found at https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-inotify/:

> **Monitor Linux file system events with inotify**
>
> ...
>
> Before inotify there was dnotify. Unfortunately, dnotify had
>   limitations that left users hoping for something better. Some of the
>   advantages of inotify are:
>
> - Inotify uses a single file descriptor, while dnotify requires opening one file descriptor for each directory that you intend to
>     watch for changes. This can be very costly when you are monitoring
>     several directories at once, and you may even reach a per-process file
>     descriptor limit.
> - The file descriptor used by inotify is obtained using a system call and does not have an associated device or file. With dnotify, the file
>     descriptor pins the directory, preventing the backing device to be
>     unmounted, a particular problem with removable media. With inotify, a
>     watched file or directory on a file system that is unmounted generates
>     an event, and the watch is automatically removed.
> - Inotify can watch files or directories. Dnotify monitors directories, and so programmers had to keep stat structures or an
>     equivalent data structure reflecting the files in the directories
>     being watched, then compare those with the current state after an
>     event occurred in order to know what happened to the entry in the
>     directory.
> - As noted above, inotify uses a file descriptor, allowing programmers to use standard select or poll functions to watch for
>     events. This allows for efficient multiplexed I/O or integration with
>     Glib's mainloop. In contrast, dnotify uses signals, which programmers
>     often find more difficult or less than elegant. Signal-drive I.O
>     notification was also added to inotify in kernel 2.6.25.
>
> **The API for inotify**
>
> ...

Note that there are no mentions of "events about to happen", or anything like that.

You don't need to keep a list of all files - you just need a list of directories - a simple `Set<String>` should do just fine.  If the deleted `String path` is in the set, it was a directory.

For a more robust approach, when you start your watch you can also put a `FileObserver` watch on all directories in the directory you're primarily watching (also add a watch to every directory created in your primary directory after you've created your watcher).

Then if you get a `DELETE_SELF` from one of the child `FileObserver` objects, you'll know it was a directory.  If the event doesn't have an associated child `FileObserver` object that got a `DELETE_SELF` event, it wasn't a directory.

For an extremely large directory, this approach admittedly will have scalability problems...

Comment: Thank you for this nice insight, it got me thinking in different direction. Although I still believe there are some precursors to thees two events, and I'm hopping Android has access to them. 
Also I do already use similar approach to the proposed one to make the check for file "type"  in constant time...